# Cross referencing XSL files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Let's say, I have an XML that uses two XSL files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="first.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="second.xsl"?>

<name>
        <firstname>Andy</firstname>
        <lastname>Ray</lastname>
</name>
```

The first XSL file is to import the template transformation from the second XSL file and display the output.

first XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:import href="second.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
  <xsl:apply-imports/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

second XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
<xsl:for-each select="name">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(firstname,lastname)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All three files are located in my local folder.

How can I view the final output from the first XSL? Do I have to save it as a .html file and then run it on IE or is there an online XSLT editor which accepts multiple XSL file inputs and displays the output?

I'm new to this language so any guidance you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any product that does anything useful with multiple xml-stylesheet processing instructions. I know that some processors choose the last one, and some choose the first.

If you want to run a pipeline of transformations (where each one takes as input the output of the previous one), then there are various ways you could control this: for example, using XProc, or Ant, or custom Java code, or xmlsh.